# Cannot get jQuery to get 2 values of input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am developing a little script on jsfiddle.com

I can get it to work with one element like in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8hXGq/3/

Here's the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $("input[name=action]").click(function() {
    value = $(':Password').val();
    alert(value); 
  });
})
```

but then when I try to get 2 input values like in this jsfiddle it does not work

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/8hXGq/2/

Here's the jQuery code

```
jQuery(function(){
$("input[name=action]").click(function(){
    newas = $(':Login').val();

    value = $(':Password').val();
    alert(value); 
    alert(newas);
});
})
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: It is good practice to not making variables global. Put `var` in the in front of variable names in declaration.

Comment: When you see `:` in a selector it means a _pseudo-class_ and may even mean a _pseudo-element_ (these have been re-defined to be `::` in CSS3). There are no such _pseudo-classes_ or _pseudo-elements_ that I can see in your _HTML_ that match `:Login`. Perhaps you want to consider what the selector you really want is, http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 3):

`':Password'` is shorthand for `input[type="password]` thus works. Your problem is `$(':Login')` here you are looking for element `input[type="Login]` which doesn't exists

Use

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("input[name=action]").click(function () {
        newas = $("input[name=Login]").val();
        alert(newas);

        value = $(':Password').val();
        alert(value);
    });
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8hXGq/8/)

Comment: I was not aware of this shorthand in _jQuery_, do you know the webpage/s where it is documented?

Comment: @PaulS. Read [:Password](https://api.jquery.com/password-selector/) and [More of this type](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/jquery-selector-extensions/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
$("input[name=action]").click(function(){
    newas = $('input[name=Login]').val();

    value = $('input[name=Password]').val();
    alert(value); 
    alert(newas);
});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8hXGq/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

if get value on the basis of name property then use it:

```
jQuery(function () {
        $("input[name=action]").click(function () {
            var newas = $('input[name=Login]').val();
            var value = $('input[name=Password]').val();

            alert(value);
            alert(newas);
        });
    });
```

If get value on the basis of id then use it:

```
jQuery(function () {
        $("input[name=action]").click(function () {
            var newas = $("input[id$='Login']").val();
            var value = $("input[id$='Password']").val()

            alert(value);
            alert(newas);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery to look like this

```
jQuery(function(){
$("input[name=action]").click(function(){
    newas = $('[name=Login]').val();

    value = $('[name=Password]').val();
    alert(value); 
    alert(newas);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`:Password` is pseudo for type password, not for name. To access by name use `[name=Login]`.

Also use var keyword as without var you initialized two global variable which is not allowed in ecmascript 5 strict mode and cause confusion sometime:

```
jQuery(function () {
    $("input[name=action]").click(function () {
        var newas = $('input[name=Login]').val();
        var value = $(':Password').val();
        alert(value);
        alert(newas);
    });
})
```

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hXGq/10/)

Answer (score 0):

:password is the Password selector of jQuery, thats why its not working with other pseudos.
https://api.jquery.com/password-selector/

i recommend NOT to do it how you did. instead it'll be better to acces by IDs.

this is working:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vy23k/1/

```
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" name="login" id="login" />
<input type="password" size="32" maxlength="64" name="password" autocomplete="off" id="password" />
<input type="submit" name="action" class="button" value="Preview">

jQuery(function(){
    $("input[name=action]").click(function(){
        login = $("#login").val();
        //pw = $(':Password').val();  //pseudo selector
        pw = $("#password").val();   //better way

        alert(login + " - " + pw); 

    });
})
```